# cocoa ghost uiview - can not access to my ivar after init

Tags: iphone, uiview, ivar

i have a strange problem :
when creating a view from a UIView subclass, into an instance of an other UIView subclass, i have access to the object only in the method in which i create it.
Into other methods, the object is NULL : i can not access or modify or remove the object from the superview.
the code (simplified):

```
// the first class (named Table):
@class Image;
@interface Table : UIView {
   Image *image;
   }
@end

#import "Image.h"
@implementation Table
- init{
    if((self = [super init])) {
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 416, 320, 416);
    self.tag = 416;
    // (blah...blah...)
    }
  return self;
  }
@end

// the second class (named Image):
@class Table 
@interface Image : UIView{ 
Table *vueGbif; 
}
-(void) createGbif;
-(void) removeGbif; 
@end

#import "Table.h" 
@implementation Image
-(void) createGbif{ 
vueGbif = [[Table alloc] init]; 
[self addSubview:vueGbif]; 
vueGbif.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416); //<-- here, "vueGbif" 
// is not null and can be set 
}

-(void) removeGbif{ 
[vueGbif removeFromSuperview]; //<-- here, vueGbif
// no longer exists : NSLog returns "null". 
} 
@end
```

Edit : 
The problem is at this time,  very strange...
In fact, actually i have access to the iVar "vueGbif" only if I invoke the method "removeGbif" from within the second class (i create the instance of the first class in this one), for example with an action on a buttton.
In this case, the instruction "removeFromSuperview" is correctly executed, and the view created is removed. And "vueGbif" exists and is not NULL.
But...
If i add a button to the view "vueGbif", when creating it and adding it to the current view (which is an instance of the second class), and later, if i touch this button to trigger "removeGbif" in the second class, at this time, "vueGbif" is equal to NULL in the second class, and removeFromSuperview doesn't work at all.

Any idea ?

Comment: Is that code exactly how it really appears in your file? You didn't accidentally mask the ivar by writing something like `Table* vueGbif = [[Table alloc] init];` did you? Also, is anybody specifically making it nil, like calling `[image setVueGbif:nil];` or something from inside the Table class?

Comment: hello, Jason, no, i don't accidentaly mask the ivar and nobody makes it nil before i need to. I have edited my question to add some precisions...